# How to AddForce in direction of mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have been searching for over an hour, I am getting a headache lol. So I'm working on a super simple 2D game, everything is done basically. However, I don't have an android device or tablet. Therefor, I can't test out the controls properly. In the meantime, I still want to develop the game, so I decided to create a mouse input instead.

The controls are simple, you have a player object, and to replicate touch/swiping, click/drag/release.

- Click and Drag in any direction
- Release adding force in direction of mouse position in relation to PlayerObject position on release.

Kind of like just small pushes in any direction. How can I go about this?

EDIT: I made it apply force, but not how I desire.  So with this code its using the center of screen as the base. So if I click in the bottom half of the screen its always forcing it down.

```
 mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        Vector2 dir = new Vector3(mousePos.x - rb.transform.position.x, mousePos.y - rb.transform.position.x);
        Debug.Log("Applying Force in Dir: " + dir);
        rb.AddForce(dir * multiplier);
    }
```

Comment: vector 2 = new vector3(x,x,x) ?

Comment: @JustARandomWibuuuu hehe lol .. but actually it doesn't really matter ;) There is an implicit conversion between `Vector3` and `Vector2` (and wise versa) which is simply ignoring the Z component. Since OP anyway uses the constructor `Vector3(x, y)` the Z will simply be `0` and then "forgotten" ... still of course a little useless overhead ;)

Comment: yeah, but some pp will misunderstand it :v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to

- MouseDown/TouchBegin on your object
- Drag the mouse/touch in a certain diretcion to define a direction + strength
- Release the mouse/touch in order o apply force to the object according to the dragged vector

I would rather use [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html), [`OnMouseDrag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html) and [`OnMouseUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html) as these an later 1-1 be also used for touch input.

I would start with a very generic re-usable class like e.g.

```
// Just a helper class for passing on all relevant data
[Serializable]
public class DragAndReleaseData2D
{
    public readonly Vector2 StartPosition;
    public readonly Vector2 EndPosition;

    public DragAndReleaseData2D(Vector2 startPosition, Vector2 endPosition)
    {
        StartPosition = startPosition;
        EndPosition = endPosition;
    }
}

public class DragAndReleaseEventHandler2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    // If possible already reference the camera via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

    // General events like the button onClick where you can attach your callback(s) to
    // either via code or in the Inspector
    public UnityEvent<Vector2> onDragBegin;
    public UnityEvent<DragAndReleaseData2D> onDragMoved;
    public UnityEvent<DragAndReleaseData2D> onDragReleased;

    // here we will store the initial position every time a new drag begins
    private Vector2 initialPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // As fallback get the main camera once
        if (!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    // this is called by Unity if Mouse (or touch) goes down over this Collider
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // Store the initial position
        initialPosition = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        // Let all listeners know by raising according event
        onDragBegin.Invoke(initialPosition);
    }

    // This is called repeatedly if OnMouseDown was called for this Collider and the mouse/touch was dragged afterwards
    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        // get the current position
        var currentPosition = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        // pass on initial and current position to listeners
        onDragMoved.Invoke(new DragAndReleaseData2D(initialPosition, currentPosition));
    }

    // This is called if OnMouseDown was called for this Collider and the mouse/touch was released
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        // Basically d the same as in OnMouseDrag just with a different event at the end

        Vector2 currentPosition = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        onDragReleased.Invoke(new DragAndReleaseData2D(initialPosition, currentPosition));
    }
}
```

Now you can easily create listener components which will react to these events like e.g.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D _rigibody;

    [SerializeField] private DragAndReleaseEventHandler2D _dragAndReleaseHandler;

    // Adjust these according to your needs

    // A multiplier applied to the given drag vector
    [SerializeField] private float multiplier = 200;
    // Maximum applied force, after applying the multiplier the vector will be clamped to maximum this magnitude
    [SerializeField] private float maxForce = 400;
    
    void Awake()
    {
        if (!_rigibody) _rigibody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (!_dragAndReleaseHandler) _dragAndReleaseHandler = GetComponent<DragAndReleaseEventHandler2D>();
        
        // Register a callback to the release event
        _dragAndReleaseHandler.onDragReleased.AddListener(OnDragReleased);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        // in general remove event listeners as soon as not needed anymore to avoid exceptions
        _dragAndReleaseHandler.onDragReleased.RemoveListener(OnDragReleased);
    }

    // Called every time the drag is released 
    void OnDragReleased(DragAndReleaseData2D dragAndReleaseData)
    {
        // 1. Get the vector from the drag (end - start)
        // 2. Multiply it by the multiplier
        // 3. Clamp the vector to apply the maxForce magnitude
        var force = Vector2.ClampMagnitude((dragAndReleaseData.EndPosition - dragAndReleaseData.StartPosition) * multiplier), maxForce);
        
        _rigibody.AddForce(force);
    }
}
```

And just t show why using this concept of a generic event handler I added a second listener which isn't even necessarily attached to the same `GameObject` but can listen and react to the same events:

```
// Use a LineRenderer to visualize the drag input
public class DragAndReleaseVisualizer2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    // These components can but don't have to sit on the same GameObject
    // Simply reference them via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer _line;
    [SerializeField] privae DragAndReleaseEventHandler2D _dragAndReleaseHandler;
    
    void Awake()
    {
        // Only as fallback look for the components on the same GameObject
        if (!_line) _line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!_dragAndReleaseHandler) _dragAndReleaseHandler = GetComponent<DragAndReleaseEventHandler2D>();

        // Set up the line and initially hide it
        _line.enabled = false;
        _line.positionCount = 2;
        
        // listen to all events
        _dragAndReleaseHandler.onDragBegin.AddListener(OnDragBegin);
        _dragAndReleaseHandler.onDragMoved.AddListener(OnDragMoved);
        _dragAndReleaseHandler.onDragReleased.AddListener(OnDragReleased);
    }

    void OnDragBegin(Vector2 position)
    { 
        // Update the positions and enable the line
        _line.SetPosition(0, position);
        _line.SetPosition(1, position);
        _line.enabled = true;
    }
    
    void OnDragMoved(DragAndReleaseData2D dragAndReleaseData)
    {
        // Update the end position
        _line.SetPosition(1, dragAndReleaseData.EndPosition);
    }

    void OnDragReleased(DragAndReleaseData2D dragAndReleaseData)
    {
        // Disable the line
        _line.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

---

And this is how it could look like

[image]

The objects with attached components

```
Cube
 |--BoxCollider2D
 |--Rigidbody2D
 |--DragAndReleaseEventHandler2D
 |--Example
Visualizer
 |--LineRenderer
 |--DragAndReleaseVisualizer2D (with reference to Cube's DragAndReleaseEventHandler2D)
Floor
 |--BoxCollder2D
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the functionality I was going for. I really appreciate the time you took to lay this out so simply and defined.